# Obtain browser url value in php

Tags: php, url

How to get address in the browser using php. 
I want a way in which I can fetch the url value that is present in the browser. If I manually add a #tag to the existing url then I want to retrieve that as well.

I have used this code till now, but I want to retrieve https  or http whatever value is in the browser.

Also this is my url:
http://example.com/xyz/?p=65

but suppose I build up the 2nd url manually then I would like to retrieve that as well
http://example.com/xyz/?p=65#fsgsg

```
      $Path=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
      echo  $URI= 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$Path;
```

Comment: the hash tag part is not send to the server, this is only used to scroll to a certain element or in javascript

Comment: 2nd url part, Javascript can do that.

Comment: the "#tag" is not sent to the server so the only way to do this would be with some javsscript to send it manually

Comment: Take a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php



Hope this do the magic.

Comment: @user3230561 consider accepting my answer to prevent this question from getting more unneeded attention, or if my answer didn't solve your problem, use the comments section to ask for further detail.

Answer (score 1):

The part behind the # is not delivered to the browser. You could however run a tiny javascript that sends you that information since it is available to the DOM (But do you really want that?) via the window object.

Answer (score 0):

For getting has parameter,use below --

```
$url = 'http://amitbera.com/path?arg=value#anchor';

print_r(parse_url($url));

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
```

More details in http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Also,For gettting  arg value use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to handle that parameter in `javascript` because the # (hash) part wont get sent to the backend side, You can just detect click of the target element in `JS` and then glue the # part as a parameter like '&hashValue=fsgsg'.

I hope that helps You in some way.